# How to get current directory related path from windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to know how can we get current directory of batch file and parent directories of batch file.
It will be easy to explain by example.
Lets assume my batch file location D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc\xyz.bat
How to get below locations from xyz.bat

1. D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc ->
2. D:\Ashish\Gupta ->
3. D:\Ashish ->
4. D: ->

I tried to search on internet and get couple of answers but still confused.

Comment: [`%~f0`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) refers to the batch script, `%~dp0.` to its parent directory, `%~dp0..` to its grand-parent, `%~dp0..\..` to its grand-grand-parent, etc.…

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PUSHD ..` with a `for /L loop` and `If` conditional statements until you reach the root directory, like so:

```bat
@Echo off & CD "%~dp0"
 Set "Path[0]=%~dp0"
  Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  PUSHD ..
  For /L %%i in (1 1 20)Do (
    If /I not "!CD!" == "!LastDir!" (
    Set "Path[%%i]=!CD!"
    Set "Root{i}=%%i"
    Set "LastDir=!Path[%%i]!"
    PUSHD ..
   )
  )
 Set Path[
 Set Root{
 For /L %%i in (0 1 %Root{i}%) Do POPD
 ECHO %CD%
 Endlocal
```

The above creates a zero indexed array of the parent folders right back to the root drive.
the 20 value used in the for /L loop iterations is a fairly arbitrary number - I can't see many situations where you'll be nesting that many subfolders, however if for some reason you have deeply nested subfolders, you may need to increase the number of iterations.

Comment: note, the above will consume any `!` characters in folder names due to delayed expansion - if thats going to be an issue, you'll need to modify the approach slightly so that the reference variable path[%%i] is defined in an environment with delayed expansion disabled

Answer (score 0):

That is very simple to achieve:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FilePath=%~dp0"
:ParsePath
for %%I in ("%FilePath%.") do (
    echo %%~fI
    set "FilePath=%%~dpI"
    if not "%%~dI\" == "%%~dpI" if not "%%~dpI" == "%%~fI" goto ParsePath
    if not "%%~dpI" == "%FilePath%" echo %%~dI\
)
endlocal
pause
```

The batch file defines first the execution environment with the first two command lines.

Then it assigns the full path of the batch file always ending with a backslash to the environment variable `FilePath`.

The command `for` is used to get the string left to last backslash in environment variable `FilePath` (drive and path) and the string right to last backslash in environment variable `FilePath` (current folder name).

The `.` is appended to string assigned to `FilePath` to force command `for` to access the file system to get the current file path without a backslash at end. The dot means current directory. So on first iteration of the `for` loop `D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc\` is extended to `D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc\.` and for that reason `%%~fI` expands to `D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc` while `%%~dpI` expands to `D:\Ashish\Gupta\` for the next loop run.

`%%~fI` and `%%~dpI` would expand on first loop run both to `D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc\` if just `"%FilePath%"` without `.` would be used because of in this case the file/folder string defines already an absolute path not containing anymore any relative part and so `for` would not access the file system to determine full file/folder name and full path of file/folder.

It is possible to use command `for` to split up a file/folder string of a file or folder which does not exist at all. There is `if exist` to check if a file/folder exists. The command `for` is **not** designed for file/folder existence checks. There are lots of uses cases on which `for` is used to split up a full qualified file name into file path and file name + extension without file already existing yet.

One directory name after the other is removed from `FilePath` until there is left only either drive letter + colon + backslash like `C:\` or `\\ComputerName\` in case of batch file is stored on a network resource accessed using UNC path.

The condition `if not "%%~dI\" == "%%~dpI"` is **not** true on root directory of the drive is the remaining file path.

The condition `if not "%%~dpI" == "%%~fI"` is **not** true on `\\ComputerName\` is the remaining file path.

So the top level is reached if one of these two conditions is not true anymore and for that reason there is no more `goto ParsePath` executed to parse the remaining file path once more. There is instead output the root directory path of the drive if the batch file was not called using a UNC path and the batch file is not stored in root directory of a drive.

The batch file outputs on running `D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc\ParsePath.bat`:

```
D:\Ashish\Gupta\abc
D:\Ashish\Gupta
D:\Ashish
D:\
```

The batch file outputs on running `D:\ParsePath.bat`:

```
D:\
```

The batch file outputs on running `\\GuptaMachine\D$\Ashish\Gupta\abc\ParsePath.bat`:

```
\\GuptaMachine\D$\Ashish\Gupta\abc
\\GuptaMachine\D$\Ashish\Gupta
\\GuptaMachine\D$\Ashish\
\\GuptaMachine\D$
\\GuptaMachine\
```

See also the output of following command lines in batch file:

```
for %%I in ("%~dp0.") do (
    echo Batch file folder name: %%~nxI
    echo Batch file folder path: %%~fI
)
```

I recommend to read also the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) as it is also possible to use `..` or `..\..` with `%~dp0` to get the folder path of one of the parent folders on being sure there are parent folders as the batch file is never stored in root folder of a drive.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains how to reference batch file arguments like argument 0 which is the batch file itself.
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`